# Issue with system restore point on windows8

Tags: windows, windows-8, system-restore

I'm developing one software and found a problem connected with system restore points.

The *problem* occurred on machine which runs windows-8. But I think it is not connected with OS but connected with some setting of windows.

One of the features is creating system restore point. It works once per day. If I create restore point I cannot create another, but if I change data I can create another one.

Can someone advice that kind of setting should be changed to create as much restore points as I want.

I can create as many restore points as I want if I use windows tool, but I can create only one if I use my own program. Not sure if helpful, but for restore point creation I use `SRSetRestorePoint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Applications should create this key to use it because it will not
>   preexist in the system. The following will apply by default if the key
>   does not exist. If an application calls the SRSetRestorePoint function
>   to create a restore point, Windows skips creating this new restore
>   point if any restore points have been created in the last 24 hours.

I think this may solve your problem.

> Developers can write applications that create the **DWORD** value
>   **SystemRestorePointCreationFrequency** under the registry key
>   **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore**. The
>   value of this registry key can change the frequency of restore point
>   creation. The value of this registry key can change the frequency of
>   restore point creation.

From [`Msdn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).